# What is the pinout for this crt connector and how to get VGA output from it?

Tags: vga, crt

Im working on a PCM 3353 board and I want to get a video output from it. i read the user manual but it only said which connector was for the crt but i want the pinout for the port.

Is there a way to connect it to the standard VGA? I found this adapter on AliExpress but it does not provide shipping to my country.

[Adapter to VGA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sPl3.png)

[PCM 3353](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5xn9.jpg)

[Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76xsn.jpg)

Is there a way to get a VGA output of this board?

Comment: Do you have a picture of this "crt" connector? I know what CRT screens are, but am unable to find a connector called a "crt connector".

Comment: Sorry i forget to upload it. i edited my post

Comment: The manual for that board absolutely does tell you the pinout for CN27 which is the VGA connector. https://advdownload.advantech.com/productfile/Downloadfile4/1-240JPT/PCM-3353_user%20manual_ed1.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much i found it